# How to programmatically get value of App specific Cellular data toggle on iOS?

Tags: ios, core-location

My iOS app uses Core Location region monitoring. Whenever a device exits a region, app contact the server to fetch new data. Everything is setup properly and it works on both WIFI and Cellular.

The problem is that user can toggle "Use Cellular Data" to OFF for my app on the device Settings.app. In this case the app will not be able to reach the server on region exit. Right now this is treated exactly like it would had there be no internet connection at all. (which is also fine).

I want to analyze how many people have deliberately turned off cellular data for my app or system-wide. I want to do this to measure if this feature is worth building. If more than n% of all users have cellular data turned off (for my app or system-wide), then it is not be worth investing further in this feature. The app is used 'in-the-wild' so cellular data is deal breaker.

If I can figure out somehow that a certain device/user has Cellular Data turned off for the app or system wide, I will be able to make the decision in a better way. Otherwise, I'll just roll out the MVP and figure it out in some other way.

Comment: You can't know.  All you know is that the Internet isn't available